# Error con FTP (Filezilla)

Tags: ftp, filezilla, tls, vsftp

He tenido un problemon, ya que después de haber pagado el servidor de Minecraft no me deja subir los archivos por la pagina web así que hable con el soporte y me dijeron que utilizase Filezilla ( también me pasaron un vídeo de su canal oficial para enseñarme los pasos ). Lo seguí a la perfección ( tampoco era muy difícil ) pero cuando lo iniciaba/inicio me sale este error:

```
Estado: Conectando a 134.255.253.139:21...
Estado: Conexión establecida, esperando el mensaje de bienvenida...
Respuesta:  220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Error:  No se pudo conectar al servidor
Estado: Esperando para reintentar...
Estado: Conectando a 134.255.253.139:21...
Estado: Conexión establecida, esperando el mensaje de bienvenida...
Respuesta:  220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Error:  No se pudo conectar al servidor
```

Se supone que lo debo probar con `FTP explicito sobre TLS`, pero como no me dio resultado lo he estado probando en `implícito` y `plano`, pero ninguna me ha dado resultado.

Estoy cansado de mandar mensajes al soporte y que no me respondan por eso he decidido postearlo aquí

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error. Si te da un fallo como este lo único que hay que hacer es encontrar una VPN del país en el que se ubique el FTP.

Ejemplo: Mi FTP está en Alemania pues con una VPN te cambias la ip a una alemana y se solucionaría